# Flex get canvas ID?

Tags: apache-flex

I'm developing an engine to generate components. I want to get the XML script that reads and creates a component to load the component directly into the canvas 'content'. I not sure how I get the addChild() method to work correctly as in 'content'.addChild instead of the implementation shown below:

```
private function sidebar():void 
{
   xmlReq = new URLRequest("sidebar.xml");
   callReq(content);
}

private function callReq(cholder:Canvas):void 
{
   getHolder = cholder;
   getHolder.addChild(...)
}

<mx:Canvas x="0" y="123" width="100%" height="200" id="content">
 </mx:Canvas>
```

Comment: Does your code ever actually tell the URLRequest to be loaded anywhere?  It might be worthwhile to confirm that callReq is getting called at all.

Comment: yes, it did called, currently, I use another callLater() method to load the second xml after the first one is done.

I manage to get it work the correct way. Is there a beter way other than callLater?

Answer (score 0):

Start by Changing

```
getHolder = cholder;
```

to

```
var getHolder:Canvas = cholder;
```